# How to allow access via CORS to multiple domains within nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

I was having some issues getting SVGs to load on my website if you were viewing website.com instead of www.website.com. The website is on an nginx server, so I added this, and it solved the issue:

```
location / {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"; 
}
```

However, based off what i've read, it seems like this is causes a security problem? Is there a way to only specify www.website.com and website.com instead of *? I ask because I came across this in PHP and it seems like what I need but for nginx:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.website.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://website.com');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: @StephenKing not a dupe as this is asking for nginx implementation specifically.

Comment: You can scroll down on that page? ;-)

Comment: I get that, but you have to go wading through [incorrect answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4110601/1048705), Apache answers, PHP implementations, etc.

Answer (score 36):

The [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explains that multiple origins can be specified by a space-separated list.  In practice, though, this is unlikely to be interpreted correctly by current implementations in browsers (eg fails for Firefox 45 at time of writing); summed up by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818477/1048705).

To implement what you need, then the following nginx snippet will check the incoming `Origin` header and adjust the response accordingly:

```
location / {
    if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://(website.com|www.website.com)$") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
    }
}
```

Add more domains into the regular expression as required; the `s?` can be removed if you want to solely support `http://`.

For note, if you're including SVGs directly on a web page via HTML (eg `<img src="http://example.com/img.svg>`), then CORS and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` aren't required. If you're using the `crossorigin` attribute for your images (such as [CORS Enabled Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)), or loading via JS etc then the above is needed.

---

**Original answer to adding multiple headers with the same name in nginx (CORS references removed as they were incorrect):**

You can use `add_header` multiple times in a given block:

```
location / {
  add_header Header-Name "value"; 
  add_header Header-Name "value2"; 
}
```

and your response will contain:

```
Header-Name: value
Header-Name: value2
```

`add_header` can also feature variables and note that you might want to add the `always` parameter (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) if you want headers to be added to all response codes, including errors.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I do that: 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.website.com/image.svg. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://www.website.com, http://website.com', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://website.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @Shonna Adjusted the answer as the aim isn't to use multiple headers as CORS uses just one header.

Comment: Be aware of the unexpected consequences of using `if` inside a location block. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ and https://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html

Comment: `if` inside `location` is not a good idea, read the [ifisevil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article

Answer (score 25):

Here is a solution that uses `map`.

This setup allows you to make requests to any subdomain and any port on my-domain.com.

```
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?my-domain.com(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    # NGINX won't set empty string headers, so if no match, header is unset.
    default "";
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
    # ...
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

There are some unexpected things that occur when using `if` inside location blocks in NGINX. It's not recommended. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ and https://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html

Comment: Thanks, his did the trick for me as the `if` has some unexpected side effects as you mentioned.

Comment: This looked promising, but I couldn't get it working. It seemed to have no effect.

Comment: origin isn't a default http header, browsers won't send it. You probably want to use `http_host` and edit the regular expressions to not include the protocoll (http://)

Comment: That's the best answer in my opinion. Clean and straight forward. Thanks, @eric-ihli

Comment: If server behind nginx add own cors headers you can hide it with `proxy_hide_header`
```
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?localhost(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?my.domain.org(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    default "*";
}

server {
...
location / {
  proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '...';
  }
}
```